# Magnify button on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Is there a way to magnify a button when you touch it? similar to the keyboard when writing a text message, the key you press gets magnified so you can see which button you are actually pressing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this by this method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

and when the user touches your button then you can change the button's frame (`buttton.frame`).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to have two different appearers of your button and it can be achieved through the your button states : [Link to state](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState):

```
 UIControlStateNormal,
   UIControlStateHighlighted,
```

Now you need to use the following set of function

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state
- (void)setTitleColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state
- (void)setTitleShadowColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state
```

[Read Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Hope your could magnify your button to some extend.